# how to hide eclipse rcp viewpart borders

Tags: eclipse, rcp, border-layout

Within the View RCP , I'm trying to figure out how to modify or hide the standard 1-pixel black border around each view, or if it's even possible. Anybody know how? 
The view is created using standard rcp viewpart extension

Any help or pointers will be helpful
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the border around the views if you modifiy the view's parent layout in `ViewPart#createPartControl` in one of your views like this:

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    Composite view_parent = parent.getParent().getParent().getParent();

    StackLayout stack_layout = (StackLayout) view_parent.getLayout();
    stack_layout.marginHeight = -1;
    stack_layout.marginWidth = -1;

    // Your code
}
```

After that you should set the views attributes:

- `standalone` to `true`
- `showTitle` to `false`

Unfortunately the border of the *"resizer"* between the views is still there. If I find a solution for that I will update my answer.

*Note:* If you have just one view, everything looks nice.

Comment: Hello Tim, Thanks for the reply. For us, we are having multiple views to be shown at startup...like eclipse IDE(projectExmplore,console, outline). so if I try to use above mentioned code in such scenario, it is not working. If you find any other solution, please post here.